# Enabling Outlook Plugin In Preview Mode

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have created an extension that extracts some parameters for the email and forwards it to our platform. It's working fine but now I want to make sure that my extension works even in preview mode. We don't have to open an email in order to use an extension.
I couldn't find any configuration to enable the plugin in preview mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to handle the `SelectionChange` event of the `Explorer` class. It is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. This event also occurs when the user (either programmatically or via the user interface) clicks or switches to a different folder that contains items, because Outlook automatically selects the first item in that folder. However, this event does not occur if the folder is a file-system folder or if any folder with a current Web view is displayed.

```
Public WithEvents myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer  
 
Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer  
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myOlExp_SelectionChange()  
 MsgBox myOlExp.Selection.Count & " items selected."  
End Sub
```

The [Explorer.Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window. Here is the sample how you can deal with the `Selection` object:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems() 
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
 Dim mySender As Outlook.AddressEntry 
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 Dim strSenderID As String 
 Const PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102"  
 Dim MsgTxt As String  
 Dim x As Long 
 
 MsgTxt = "Senders of selected items:"  
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer  
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection  
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count  
 If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then  
 ' For mail item, use the SenderName property.  
 Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x)  
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oMail.SenderName & ";"  
 ElseIf myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then  
 ' For appointment item, use the Organizer property.  
 Set oAppt = myOlSel.Item(x)  
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oAppt.Organizer & ";"  
 Else  
 ' For other items, use the property accessor to get the sender ID,  
 ' then get the address entry to display the sender name.  
 Set oPA = myOlSel.Item(x).PropertyAccessor  
 strSenderID = oPA.GetProperty(PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID)  
 Set mySender = Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(strSenderID)  
 MsgTxt = MsgTxt & mySender.Name & ";"  
 End If  
 Next x  
 Debug.Print MsgTxt  
End Sub
```